# how to make back option in toolbar/ActionBar when I move from one fragment to other

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I am facing the problem in android regarding with Fragments.
See I am using Navigation drawer activity. Inside that home fragment is placed. After pressing a button in home fragment, it will move to second fragment. So my problem is how to navigate back icon option in tool bar, so that I can move back to home fragment from second fragment with the help of tool bar, like flipkart app.
In flipkart app, inside navigation drawer fragment, if we select an item it moved to that fragment. Then it creates back option in tool bar to navigate back to the main fragment.
please anyone help

Comment: I have used this . But this works in from one activity to another activity. But I need from one fragment to another

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or (if you use appcompat `ActionBar`)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have used this . But this works in from one activity to another activity. But I need from one fragment to another

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or(if your activity is AppCompat then )

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have used this . But this works in from one activity to another activity. But I need from one fragment to another

Comment: @vini this is for fragment. otherwise Phan give answer that is for activity.